# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string for the library: react-jsonschema-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m tryign to replicate the demo of this library: https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

To automate the creation of forms, specifically, I'm trying with this example:

[image]

For that I'm following these steps:

1) Create a project using: `npm init react-app formapp`
2) Install de dependencies: yarn  add react-jsonschema-form

Just after this step, if I run the app as: npm start

I get:

[image]

3) I'm overwriting app.Js with the code:

```
require("react/package.json"); // react is a peer dependency. 
var JSONSchemaForm = require("react-jsonschema-form")
const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
const schema = {
  title: "Test form",
  type: "string"
};
```

4) Start the app:

From there I get the following message in the console:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 5:7:  'Form' is assigned a value but never used    no-unused-vars
  Line 6:7:  'schema' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

And this in the server

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.js, use `import` instead of `require`.

```js
import React from "react";
import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";
...
```

Refer the [example implementation and code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jsonschema-form-bgjbc)